# Common UIButton or UIbarbutton to navigationbar

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

How can we add common UIButton or UIBarButton or any UI object so that it appears in all navigationbars in the application.

Comment: You need to add a category extension to UiNavigationBar, or a subclass

Answer (score 0):

```
The below code will work perfectly;

UIImage* image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"];
CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0, image3.size.width*4, image3.size.height);
UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
//[someButton setBackgroundImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton setTitle:@"Category" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popUpPicker:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];

UIBarButtonItem *mailbutton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=mailbutton;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

For these, you have to use category and then you have to call it in your every view controller to have the one code for every navigationabr button action.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic formula. One way or another, you have to add the same "UIButton or UIBarButton or any UI object" to the `navigationItem` of every UIViewController whose view will appear under this navigation controller's navigation bar.

You can reduce the amount of repeated code by creating this object in a single place, but the act of saying

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = thisItem
```

or whatever it is you want to do with the bar button item, will have to be performed separately and explicitly for every view controller.